# QTableView and custom ORM

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

Do you have any ideas, examples how to use `QTableView` with a custom ORM written in Python (for example `Web2Py DAL`).

So i have result of a query and fields describing properties of columns in that result:

```
ID (int)  Name (str)
1         Lisa
2         Maria
```

I want to make a class `ResultSetModel` which can be tied to a `QTableView`. I can have many objects of this class, each with its own query - like in `QSqlQueryModel`. But `QSqlQueryModel` deals with SQL infrastructure in Qt, but i have my own ORM to deal with the database.

Thank you

**UPDATE :**

Let's suppose i have a table with a lot of rows. I don't want to request all of them and keep them in a model. I need a model that works together with QTableView requesting next or previous records when user scrolls down or up the view.

QAbstractItemModel.fetchMore is interesting but doesn't do what i want.

You can see the Fetch More example in `examples/itemviews/fetchmore.py`. When you scroll down to the end, it requests additional portion of data, but keeps the old records too. And it doesn't do the same when you scroll up.

Imagine that i have several million of persons in the Persons table. I want to request and keep in my model/memory only the records shown in the view.

What i am trying to achieve is shown here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQlE0rrr7wI

I.e. once the view is shown, the underlying model requests as many rows as needed to show on the screen. As you scroll down/up - the other rows is requested from DB incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example using elixir and pyside. There should be `session.commit()` there somewhere (on "save" button click or something like that). Other then that it's fully functional

```
from elixir import *
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import operator, sys

class ColumnDescriptor(object):
    #This holds properties, controlling how each field looks/behaves in GUI"""
    def __init__(self, field_id):
        self.id = field_id
        self.verbose_name = self.id.capitalize().replace('_', ' ')
        self.comment = None

class Person(Entity): #ORM entity class
    #ORM entity fields
    id_number = Field(Integer)
    name = Field(Unicode(50))

    def __init__(self, name, id_number):
        self.name = name
        self.id_number = id_number

class PersonView():

    columns = []

    col = ColumnDescriptor('id_number')
    col.comment = "Person's identification code"
    columns.append(col)

    col = ColumnDescriptor('name')
    col.verbose_name = 'Full name'
    col.comment = "Person's full name"
    columns.append(col)

    def __init__(self):
        self.total_records = Person.query.count()

    def get_items(self, limit, offset = 0):
        return Person.query.offset(offset).limit(limit).all()


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    #A one-size-fits-all model based on a view descriptor

    numberPopulated = QtCore.Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, view, editable = False, limit = 50):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self.view = view
        self.editable = editable
        self.current_page = 1
        self.items_per_page = limit
        self.items = view.get_items(self.items_per_page)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self.view.columns)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.items)

    def loadPage(self):

        self.beginResetModel()
        self.items = []
        self.endResetModel()

        self.items = self.view.get_items(self.items_per_page,
            self.current_page * self.items_per_page)

        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), 0, len(self.items))
        self.endInsertRows()
        self.numberPopulated.emit(len(self.items))

    def prevPage(self):
        self.current_page = self.current_page - 1
        self.loadPage()

    def nextPage(self):
        self.current_page = self.current_page + 1
        self.loadPage()

    def headerData(self, column, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.view.columns[column].verbose_name

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid():
            if (role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole) or (role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
                field_name = self.view.columns[index.column()].id
                value = self.items[index.row()].__getattribute__(field_name)
                if value:
                    return unicode(value)
                else:
                    return ''

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        else:
            if self.editable:
                return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
            else:
                return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.grid = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.grid.setModel(TableModel(PersonView(), True))

        self.layout.addWidget(self.grid)
        self.layoutButtons = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.layoutButtons)

        self.btnPrevious = QtGui.QPushButton("Previous", self)
        self.btnNext = QtGui.QPushButton("Next",self)
        self.layoutButtons.addWidget(self.btnPrevious)
        self.layoutButtons.addWidget(self.btnNext)

        self.btnPrevious.clicked.connect(self.grid.model().prevPage)
        self.btnNext.clicked.connect(self.grid.model().nextPage)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    metadata.bind = "sqlite:///persons.sqlite"
    setup_all(True)

    #fill the table up, if empty
    if not Person.query.all():
        for n in range(1,1000):
            p = Person(u'Person', n)

        session.commit()

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: `def rowCount(self, index): return len(self.items)` - this means items is the list of records already requested from DB. I need to request records from the DB in chunks as the user scrolls the QTableView. Also i might not know the total count or records... Smth like here: http://cep.xor.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2-browser/dc/d7c/qsqlquerymodel_8cpp-source.html#l00034

Comment: Isn't QAbstractTableModel.fetchMore() a standard way to do this?

Comment: thank you for trying to help. please read the update on the question

Comment: So what you want is pagination. Well, that's a different problem. Can you live with next page/previous page buttons, or it all has to be behind the scenes?

Comment: But will the aforementioned loading be done in batches of a fixed size and presented to the user, while all previously loaded data has to be cleared from the model and consequently removed from user's view? If yes, then it sounds like pagination to me, but I certainly am not an expert.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5560/discussion-between-warvariuc-and-alexvhr)